# Copy MemoryStream to FileStream and save the file?

Tags: c#, file-upload, filestream, memorystream

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. I generate couple of memory streams and in debug-mode I see that they are populated. But when I try to copy `MemoryStream` to `FileStream` in order to save the file `fileStream` is not populated and file is 0bytes long (empty).

Here is my code

```
if (file.ContentLength > 0)
{
    var bytes = ImageUploader.FilestreamToBytes(file); // bytes is populated

    using (var inStream = new MemoryStream(bytes)) // inStream is populated
    {
        using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var imageFactory = new ImageFactory())
            {
                imageFactory.Load(inStream)
                            .Resize(new Size(320, 0))
                            .Format(ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                            .Quality(70)
                            .Save(outStream);
            }
            
            // outStream is populated here
            
            var fileName = "test.jpg";

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/content/u/") + fileName, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                outStream.CopyTo(fileStream); // fileStream is not populated
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure outStream contains the image data? I think the problem in .Save(outStream); can you please post the call stack.

Comment: @BassamAlugili na man, I checked in debug-mode. It's populated. `outStream.Position = 0` was the problem, I needed to set it.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You need to reset the position of the stream before copying.

```
outStream.Position = 0;
outStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
```

You used the `outStream` when saving the file using the `imageFactory`. That function populated the `outStream`. While populating the `outStream` the position is set to the end of the populated area. That is so that when you keep on writing bytes to the steam, it doesn't override existing bytes. But then to read it (for copy purposes) you need to set the position to the start so you can start reading at the start.

Comment: I'm wondering why he need this Position = 0; he just created the outStream and not used; Why should he get a wrong position?

Comment: @BassamAlugili He used the outsteam when saving the file using the imageFactory. That function populated the outsteam. While populating the outstream the position is set to the end of the populated area. That is so that when you keep on writing bytes to the steam, it doesnt override existing bytes. But then to read it (for copy purposes) you need to set the position to the start so you can start reading at the start.

Answer (score 21):

If your objective is simply to dump the memory stream to a physical file (e.g. to look at the contents) - it can be done in one move:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\\filename", memoryStream.ToArray());
```

No need to set the stream position first either, since the .ToArray() operation explicitly ignores that, as per @BaconBits comment below https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.toarray?view=netframework-4.7.2.

Comment: You don't need `memoryStream.Position = 0;`.  [MemoryStream.ToArray() explicitly ignores Position](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.toarray?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative to `CopyTo` is `WriteTo`.

**Advantage:**

No need to reset Position.

**Usage:**

```
outStream.WriteTo(fileStream);
```

[**Function Description:**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.writeto?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Writes the entire contents of this memory stream to another stream.