# DropBox API calls Uploading a Zero byte file

Tags: c#, rest, api, dropbox

I am trying to upload a file to dropbox using rest calls but it is not uploading the actual file, it is uploading a zero byte file.

Please check the code and let me know if i am missing something.

```
var task = Task.Run((Func<Task<int>>)OrderExtractUsecase.DropBox);
task.Wait();
int x = task.Result;
```

Dropbox task Code is:

```
static async Task<int> DropBox()
    {
        try
        {
            Dropbox_Utility objDropBox = new Dropbox_Utility("<accessid>");
            foreach (string temp in fileList)
            {
                await objDropBox.Upload("/Assist", temp);
            }
            return 1;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Upload task code is:

```
    public async Task<string> Upload(string folder, string filefullpath)
    {
         string filename = string.Empty;
         string fileID = string.Empty;
         try
         {
            filename = Path.GetFileName(filefullpath);

            using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filefullpath))
            {
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    var response = await dbx.Files.UploadAsync(folder + "/" + filename, WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance, body: memoryStream);
                    fileID = response.Id;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { throw; }
        finally { }
        return fileID;
    }
```

Comment: You might need to reset the position of the stream before copying.  See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18766138/3617120

Comment: @awh112 not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As awh112 mentioned, you need to reset the position of `memoryStream`. After the `copyTo`, the `Position` of `memoryStream` is the length of the file. For that reason, your code will upload a zero byte file. I've confirmed as much with the following:

```
fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
Console.WriteLine(memoryStream.Position);
var response = await dbx.Files.UploadAsync(folder + "/" + filename, WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance, body: memoryStream);
Console.WriteLine((response as FileMetadata).Size);
```

That prints: (in my case, my test file is just 12 bytes long)

```
12
0
```

You can rewind it like this:

```
fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
Console.WriteLine(memoryStream.Position);
memoryStream.Position = 0;
Console.WriteLine(memoryStream.Position);
var response = await dbx.Files.UploadAsync(folder + "/" + filename, WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance, body: memoryStream);
Console.WriteLine((response as FileMetadata).Size);
```

That prints:

```
12
0
12
```

The resulting uploaded file then contains the expected contents.

Comment: @gerg It is still not uploading the file only now if i am using the secound peice of code

Comment: When i am using the above code, the below is the output i am getting, 2019880 0 2019880 @Gerg

Comment: @JiteshDammani How are you checking that? The output you shared indicates that the `memoryStream` did receive `2019880` bytes, and that the uploaded file, as evidenced by the `FileMetadata.Size` returned from the Dropbox, was also the full `2019880`.

Comment: By the way, unless you need the separate `MemoryStream` for some other reason, you should be able to forgo it entirely and just upload directly from the `FileStream`.