# C# Spire Document.SaveToStream not working

Tags: c#, spire.doc

I have the following code but it is just creating a 0kb empty file.

```
using (var stream1 = new MemoryStream())
{
    MemoryStream txtStream = new MemoryStream();
    Document document = new Document();
    fileInformation.Stream.CopyTo(stream1);
    document.LoadFromStream(stream1, FileFormat.Auto);
    document.SaveToStream(txtStream, FileFormat.Txt);

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(txtStream);
    string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName + ".txt", text);
 }
```

I know the data is successfully loaded into `document` because if do `document.SaveToTxt("test.txt", Encoding.UTF8);`
instead of the `SaveToStream` line it exports the file properly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might need to reset the stream position to 0 before copying from one to the other.  Take a look here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18766138/3617120

Comment: @awh112 I reset both streams (stream1, and txtStream) positions after calling SaveToStream and it worked!! Thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help!  I'll go ahead and add it as an answer for future readers as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When copying a stream, you need to take care to reset the position to 0 if copying.  As seen in the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18766138/3617120), you can do something like this to your streams:

```
stream1.Position = 0;
txtStream.Position = 0;
```