# Multiple files in memory stream in one result file for SevenZipCompressor

Tags: c#, zip, compression, sevenzipsharp

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/276319/492258) has been for [SharpZipLib](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib)

What could be equivelant  PutNextEntry equivalent for [SevenZipCompressor](https://github.com/phillipp/SevenZipSharp/blob/master/SevenZip/SevenZipCompressor.cs) ?

I tried

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileByteList.First().Binary);
MemoryStream compressedStream = new MemoryStream(); 
SevenZip.SevenZipCompressor compressor = new SevenZip.SevenZipCompressor();
compressor.DefaultItemName = "toto";
compressor.CompressionMethod = SevenZip.CompressionMethod.Lzma2;
compressor.CompressionLevel = SevenZip.CompressionLevel.Normal;
compressor.CompressStream(ms, compressedStream);


compressor = new SevenZip.SevenZipCompressor();
compressor.CompressionMethod = SevenZip.CompressionMethod.Lzma2;
compressor.CompressionLevel = SevenZip.CompressionLevel.Normal;
compressor.DefaultItemName = "toto2";
MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream(fileByteList[1].Binary); 
compressor.CompressStream(ms2, compressedStream);

MemoryStream ms3 = new MemoryStream();
SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor extractor = new SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor(compressedStream);
extractor.ExtractFile(0, ms3);
```

which gives error:

```
An exception of type 'SevenZip.SevenZipArchiveException' occurred in SevenZipSharp.dll but was not handled in user code
Invalid archive: open/read error! Is it encrypted and a wrong password was provided?
If your archive is an exotic one, it is possible that SevenZipSharp has no signature for its format and thus decided it is TAR by mistake. occurred
```

Comment: If you want to do Zip Compression in .NET and have the proper Framework version (4.5 or later), you usually use the ZipArchive Class. I have no knowledge of this particular 3rd party Library.

Comment: 7zip is customer requirement